# converting regular expression in PHP to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have the following PHP regex:

```
/\b([A-Z0-9]{8})\b/i
```

in which I wanted to convert to a javascript regex. So I tried the following:

```
/^(\b([A-Z0-9]{8})\b/i
```

however it failed. Why is this? I am trying to check if a string has a word that contains 8 digit of alphanumeric character, ignoring uppercase and lowercase (meaning that `2HJS1289` and `2hjs1289` should match). The string needs to have 8 digits.

Comment: First of all, *why did you make any changes at all*?

Comment: have you tried the PHP one _verbatim_?

Comment: define "it failed". what did you test, what happened? Anyway, I see 2 open brackets (`(`), and only one closeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `)`:

```
/^(\b([A-Z0-9]{8})\b)/i
```

Although, you can just use the same expression as you would for PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = /^(\b([A-Z0-9]{8})\b)/i;
var _string = "2HJS1289";

if( regex.test(_string) ){
    alert('pass');
}
else{
    alert('fail');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/2A4tA/